# Не правильно работает переключатель вариаций на странице товара. Помогите найти ошибку

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Всем доброго времени суток.
Помогите разобраться и найти ошибку.
На странице товара можно сделать выбор между двумя вариациями.
После переключения между ними не меняется цена товара - если с вариации по умолчанию переключиться на другую, цена зависает и больше никак не реагирует на выбор.
Переключатель вариаций рукописный.

Вот ссылка на страницу товара https://test1.yubikey.com.ua/shop/yubikey-5c-nfc/

И код переключателя .

```js
var DEBUG = true;

jQuery(function() {
    if(jQuery("#pa_pack").length != 0) {
        var sDefaultPack = jQuery('#pa_pack').val();
        jQuery('#'+sDefaultPack).addClass('clicked');

        var varQty = jQuery('#product-selections-div').children().length;
        if (DEBUG){console.log('default pack: ' + sDefaultPack);} // debug
        if (DEBUG){console.log('variations qty: ' + varQty);} // debug
    }
    if(jQuery("#dpd_terminal").length)
    {
        jQuery("#dpd_terminal").select2();
    }
    getDefaultPackType();
});

function setVariant(sID)
{

  if (sID != jQuery('#pa_pack').val()) // check if clicked isn't current variation
  {
    if (DEBUG){console.log('selected variation ' + sID);} // debug

    jQuery('#product-radio-div').show(); // Show package selector
    jQuery('.product-selector').removeClass('clicked');
    jQuery('#radio-individual_packaging').attr('checked',true); // Set radio button to Индивидуальная упаковка
    this.setPackTypeVariant('individual_packaging'); // Set variation to Индивидуальная упаковка
    jQuery('#'+sID).addClass('clicked');
    if (sID == 'tray_keys') // If Tray variant is checked
      {
      //  jQuery('#radio-no_packaging').attr('checked',true);
        jQuery('#product-radio-div').hide(); // Hide package selector
      }
    jQuery('#pa_pack option[value="'+sID+'"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
    jQuery("#pa_pack").change();
  //  jQuery("#woocommerce-variation-name").html("<h1>" + variationName[sID] + "</h1>");
  //  if (DEBUG){console.log('variation name ' + variationName[sID]);} // debug
  }
}
function setPackTypeVariant(sID)
{
    //jQuery('.product-selector').removeClass('clicked');
    //jQuery('#'+sID).addClass('clicked');
    jQuery('#pa_pack_type option[value="'+sID+'"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
    jQuery("#pa_pack_type").change();
}
function getDefaultPackType()
{
    if(jQuery("#pa_pack_type").length != 0) {
        sValue = jQuery("#pa_pack_type").val();
        jQuery('#radio-'+sValue).attr('checked',true);
    }
}
function CatalogFilter(sSelectedkey)
{
    jQuery('.av-section-tab-title').removeClass('av-active-tab-title');
    if(sSelectedkey=='all')
    {
        jQuery('#tab-title-all').addClass('av-active-tab-title');
        jQuery('.category-container').show();
        jQuery('.category-container .category-descr').show();
        jQuery('.category-container .small-product-desc').show();
    }
    else
    {
        jQuery('#tab-title-'+sSelectedkey).addClass('av-active-tab-title');
        jQuery('.category-container').hide();
        jQuery('.category-container-'+sSelectedkey).show();
        jQuery('.category-container-'+sSelectedkey+' .category-descr').hide();
        jQuery('.category-container-'+sSelectedkey+' .small-product-desc').hide();
    }
}

  function quantity_change_btn_click(doPlus, idS)
    {
        var number = jQuery('#'+idS.id),
                max = parseFloat( number.attr( 'max' ) ),
                min = parseFloat( number.attr( 'min' ) ),
                step = parseInt( number.attr( 'step' ), 10 );

        // --Quantity
        if (doPlus==false){
                    var the_val = parseInt( number.val(), 10 ) - step;
                    the_val = the_val < 0 ? 0 : the_val;
                    the_val = the_val < min ? min : the_val;
          number.val(the_val).trigger("change");
        }
        // ++Quantity
        else{
          var the_val = parseInt( number.val(), 10 ) + step;
          the_val = the_val > max ? max : the_val;
          number.val(the_val).trigger("change");
        }
        
  }

  // Автообновление стоимости заказа после изменения кол-ва товаров в корзине. Можно вешать на onChange
  function update_Cart()
    {
    jQuery("button[name='update_cart']").prop("disabled", false);
    jQuery("button[name='update_cart']").trigger('click');
  }

  function reload_js(src) {
    //console.log("ssssssssssss");
    jQuery('script[src="' + src + '"]').remove();
    jQuery('<script>').attr('src', src).appendTo('footer');
}

jQuery( document).on( 'updated_cart_totals', function(){
  document.location.reload(false); //Reload page. Fixing AJAX-update when you can't choose a city in DPD
});
```

Comment: речь идет про переключатель без упаковки/индивидуальная?

Comment: @2ip да так и есть.